# Anaconda connection failed when changing python version

Tags: python, http, tensorflow, anaconda

I'm in trouble concerning my Anaconda set up. I want to install keras for R using Anaconda. But when i try to install TensorFlow (using Anaconda), it says me conflicts happend. I found it was because of my python version (3.7) which is not supported by TensorFlow.

So I tried to change the version of python used by Anaconda.

I use this :

```
conda install python=3.5.0
```

But an error occure

```
Solving environment: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))
```

I tried setting my conda ssl_verify variable to false as i found here
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6007

I restarted my computer then nothing changed.

So i tried installing the last version of SSL. But Nothing changed too.

I don't think it's my network configuration because I tried to use my mobile datas and the wifi, but it didn't changed anything.

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts>conda config --show
add_anaconda_token: True
add_pip_as_python_dependency: True
aggressive_update_packages:
  - ca-certificates
  - certifi
  - openssl
allow_non_channel_urls: True
allow_softlinks: True
always_copy: False
always_softlink: False
always_yes: None
anaconda_upload: None
auto_update_conda: True
changeps1: True
channel_alias: https://conda.anaconda.org
channel_priority: True
channels:
  - defaults
client_ssl_cert: None
client_ssl_cert_key: None
clobber: False
create_default_packages: []
custom_channels:
  pkgs/main: https://repo.anaconda.com
  pkgs/free: https://repo.anaconda.com
  pkgs/r: https://repo.anaconda.com
  pkgs/pro: https://repo.anaconda.com
  pkgs/msys2: https://repo.anaconda.com
  C:/Users/Sylvain/conda-bld: file://
custom_multichannels:
  defaults: ["https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main", "https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free", "https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r", "https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro", "https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2"]
  local: ["file:///C:/Users/Sylvain/conda-bld"]
default_channels:
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2
disallowed_packages: []
download_only: False
envs_dirs:
  - C:\Users\Sylvain\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
  - C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
  - C:\Users\Sylvain\.conda\envs
extra_safety_checks: False
force: False
json: False
local_repodata_ttl: 1
max_shlvl: 2
migrated_channel_aliases: []
no_dependencies: False
non_admin_enabled: True
notify_outdated_conda: True
offline: False
override_channels_enabled: True
path_conflict: clobber
pinned_packages: []
pkgs_dirs:
  - C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs
  - C:\Users\Sylvain\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
proxy_servers: {}
quiet: False
remote_connect_timeout_secs: 9.15
remote_max_retries: 3
remote_read_timeout_secs: 60.0
report_errors: None
rollback_enabled: True
safety_checks: warn
shortcuts: True
show_channel_urls: None
ssl_verify: False
track_features: []
use_index_cache: False
use_pip: True
verbosity: 0
whitelist_channels: []
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: : Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."

This seems to be a problem with anaconda itself because others in conda github are also having problems with missing SSL as shown in your error " : Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."

This seems to be a problem with anaconda itself. The biggest clue in your error that I see is : Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.".  See the thread at https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6064 for solutions that have worked for others."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed :

I downgraded Anaconda to 3.5, it was conflicts with Anaconda 2018 and windows 10. 
Probably not the best way but the fastes one !